# what is syntax to add string into numpy array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

let say i have a string :

```
str = "string"
```

and using `np.fromstring` i got a return value :

```
array([115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103], dtype=uint8)
```

Now, i already have an array created with numpy :

```
np.zeros((3,3), dtype=int)
```

what is syntax to make my array become :

```
[[(115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103) 0 0]
                              [0 0 0]
                              [0 0 0]]
```

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far and where you've gotten stuck.

Comment: Trying to use NumPy like that is going to run into **very nasty** conflicts with NumPy's design, which is fundamentally oriented around rigid grids of numbers. You'll lose any efficiency benefit of working with NumPy, you'll have constant difficulty getting NumPy to produce the shapes you want, you'll lose the ability to use like half of NumPy's functions, etc. Seriously, don't do it.

Comment: sorry but i have no idea to do that using numpy and so i wondering if is it possible to do with numpy.. i've already tried using array instead of numpy. thank you anyway..

Comment: so is there any other way besides using numpy?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica wouldn't it be ok to turn the dtype of the array into `'O'`? Which functionalites would be lost?

Comment: @mapf: A lot of math functionality breaks, [like `sqrt`](https://ideone.com/h1mHZR), and you'll have issues with inconsistent shape handling and severely degraded performance.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Math functionality, of course. Should have thought of that. But I wasn't aware that this would severely impact the performace. Good to know, thanks! Sorry for the follow-up question, but does that mean you would generally not recommend object type numpy arrays? I use them occasionally to store data for look-up purposes, which I guess is what OP wants to do as well. I like the convenience of working with these arrays. So what would be a good alternative? Pandas dataframe? I never used them, do they work differently under the hood compared to a numpy array?

Comment: Maybe I should make this it's own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use dtype object of non symmetric arrays

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103], dtype=np.uint8)

arr = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=int)

outarray = arr.astype(object)
outarray[0,0] = arr1
outarray
array([[array([115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103], dtype=uint8), 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]], dtype=object)

outarray[0,0] = tuple(arr1)
outarray
array([[(115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103), 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Hi @AndreZee, glad I could help. if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark